# How to get notified about next and previous month selection in sap.ui.unified.Calendar

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to implement `sap.ui.unified.Calendar`<sup>[api](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar)</sup> and to fetch events month wise. I need events or methods like *Next month*, *previous month*, or *current visible month*. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974021/5846045 solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Listener for month and year change is currently unavailable.
I have same query and have raised a token on openui5 github.
you can check it on following link.

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/361

Cheers,
harshal

Comment: @kaushalpatel The feature is now available: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974021/5846045

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use in the onAfterRendering() method

```
var oView = this.getView();
var oCalendar = oView.byId("usageCalendar");
var calendarHeaderRef = sap.ui.getCore().byId(oCalendar.sId + "--Head"); 


//to disable prev and next buttons    
calendarHeaderRef.setEnabledNext(false);
    calendarHeaderRef.setEnabledPrevious(false);
```

If you would like to listen to the previous and next buttons on the calendar, you can use

```
calendarHeaderRef.attachPressNext(this.calendarNextMonthPressed);
calendarHeaderRef.attachPressPrevious(this.calendarPrevMonthPressed);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Listening to month / year selection

### In `sap.ui.unified.Calendar`

You can listen to month & year navigation by listening to `startDateChange`. Here is an example:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/unified/Calendar",
], Calendar => new Calendar({
  startDateChange: event => {
    const navigatedDate = event.getSource().getStartDate();
    const monthYearText = navigatedDate.toLocaleString("default", {
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric",
    });
    alert(`Navigating to ${monthYearText}`);
  },
}).placeAt("content")))
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

### In `sap.m.DatePicker`

In case of the `DatePicker` or controls that are derived from it (`DateTimePicker`, `DateRangeSelection`, ...), the same event is applied with the event `navigate`

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/DatePicker", // or DateTimePicker or DateRangeSelection, etc..
], DatePicker => new DatePicker({
  width: "17rem",
  placeholder: "Select month / year in Calendar -->",
  navigate: event => {
    if (!event.getParameter("afterPopupOpened")) {
      alert("Changing month / year");
    }
  }
}).placeAt("content")))
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```